# How to completely remove broken GNOME/GDM installed on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, gnome, gdm, init, purge

I have installed an Ubuntu Server. It obviously comes with no graphical interface. I tried to install one with:

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg xfonts* gnome gdm
```

Then I got an error message trying to log in with GNOME and eventually I uninstalled everything:

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg xfonts* gnome gdm
```

However, it seems Ubuntu still has some scripts trying to launch GNOME since when starting I get:

```
Starting GNOME Display Manager   fail
...
Stopping system v run level compatibility
```

And the system stops forever. (I know I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.)

What should I modify to get this completely uninstalled?  I cannot find anything in the `rc2.d` directory.

Comment: If you want to keep the server a pure server, you may want to install something like Webmin, which can give you a web-based GUI for a lot of configuration options. http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/06/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get remove` does not remove the configuration files, but since you already removed the packages you cannot purge the config files. Your best bet is to reinstall the same packages then purge them, thus removing all configuration files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xfonts* gnome gdm
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg xfonts* gnome gdm
```

Comment: I think I have it...
Removing

/etc/rcS.d/S70x11-common
and

/etc/init/gdm.conf
Not totally sure but apparently that made it!

Comment: Is it "purge" the right way to uninstall them?  I normally use "remove" but according to what you said I should always use purge to make sure configuration files are also removed

Comment: You might want to use remove if you have configured the program but the executables/libraries are corrupted, but I usually just purge it to make sure it is gone,gone,gone.

Answer (score 1):

While [as Scott Goodgame says](https://askubuntu.com/a/314783/22949) `apt-get purge` can only purge packages that are installed, `dpkg -P` does not have this limitation. So there's no need to reinstall a package for the purpose of re-uninstalling it with the `purge` action.

<sup>Those skeptical that `dpkg` has this ability can test it out, perhaps by installing, removing, and `dpkg -P`-purging a package rarely present on desktop systems, with configuration files but minimal dependencies, [such as `gamin`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8111009/).</sup>

To remove the packages' systemwide configuration files (this will also uninstall the packages if they're still installed, this acting like `sudo apt-get purge ...` in that case), run:

```
sudo dpkg -P xserver-xorg `dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package} ' -W xfonts\*` gnome gdm
```

`apt-get` matches [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) like `xfonts*`, but `dpkg` doesn't, which is the reason for the italicized [backticked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick#Use_in_programming) expression.

<sup>As a secondary matter, you might be surprised to learn `apt-get` interprets `xfonts*` as a regexp. If `xfonts*` were expanded with shell-like expansion, it would match all names starting with `xfonts`. Since it's expanded as a regexp instead, it matches all names with `xfont` (not `xfonts`, `xfont`) *anywhere* in them, including packages like `fonts-ipaexfont-gothic`. This is because, in regular expressions, `x*` means "zero or more *`x`*es." **The pattern you probably want is `^xfonts`**, which matches `xfonts` at the beginning of a package name (or of a line, in the general use case).</sup>